How to use org-drill in Emacs terminal mode
I need to use org-drill flashcards in terminal mode (emacs -nw). When I invoke org-drill, it shows me the first flash card but when I press a key to show the answer, it gives me an error:
'''org-format-latex: Window system frame should be used.'''
After this the reviewing process is halted.
I do not have any latex fragment in my cards and I do not mind not using latex feature at all. I just need to tell org-drill to forget about the latex which needs graphics and it is not available in terminal mode. I appreciate any help.
I tried reviewing a card inside an orgfile with GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.16.0)
of 2023-08-16, modified by Debian.
